# Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) Error when i import a .h class file

Tags: ios, xcode

i have a view controller called ViewController and it works with my app perfectly, but in my other viewControllers i needed to push the initial ViewController, to when i import the ViewController as below:

```
#import "AlbumsUtilities.h"
#import "PhotosUtilities.h"
#import "MyProgressHUD.h"
#import "CommonFunctionalities.h"
#import "AlbumDetailsViewController.h"
--->#import "ViewController.h"
@interface SettingsViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray<AlbumsUtilities *> *userAlbums;
@property (nonatomic, assign, getter=isReSequence) BOOL reSequence;
@end
```

i get the Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) Error, any ideas?

Comment: What does your `ViewController.h` look like? Edit your question and paste it there.

Comment: u mean u need the code or the storyboard?

Comment: Do you have an `.h` file in your Storyboard?

Comment: Did you try Menu > Product > Clean ?

Comment: no i don't think so, and yea i tried cleaning my project many times

Comment: i even created a new viewcontroller changed the name and when i try to include it, i get the same error!

Comment: Is that a `.h` or a `.m`? Did you import `SettingsViewController.h` in `ViewController.h`?

Comment: yea, i fixed the problem, turns out i declared some variables outside the interface in .h file, even though it works fine if u don't want to import ur class someplace else, placed them inside the interface implementation, that solved it, thanks anyways.